# A naive question on values of an integral polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $P(t)$ be a polynomial with integral coefficients, in one variable. I want to know what is the g.c.d. of the set $\{P(n)|n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Is it the leading coefficient of $P(t)$?

Comment: Try the polynomial $n^2+n$. Or more generally, the polynomial $(n+1)\cdots (n+k)$, where $k$ is a fixed positive integer.

Comment: If $d$ divides $P(n)$ for every $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ then in particular $d$ divides $P(0)$, i.e. the constant term of $P(t)$.

Comment: Let's say $P(x)$ has degree $p$ and leading coefficient $a_p$.
If $d$ divides $P(n)$ for every $n$, then $d$ divides the finite difference $P(n+1) - P(n)$ for every $n$. Apply finite differences $p$ times, we can conclude $d$ divides $p! a_p$. This bound is sort of optimal. For the monic polynomial $Q(x) = x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-p+1)$, we know $\gcd\{ Q(n) : n \in \mathbb{Z} \} = p!$ and above bound is achieved.

Comment: @achillehui This is the answer that I am looking for. You could make your comment into an answer, after adding some more details (for example the step of applying finite difference p times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the collection of real valued functions over $\mathbb{R}$. For any $f \in \mathcal{F}$, the [finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) of  $f$ is a function $Df \in \mathcal{F}$ defined by the relation

$$(Df)(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$$
In particular, if $P$ is a polynomial of degree $p$ with leading coefficients $a_p$, we have

$$\begin{align} P(x) & = a_p x^p + a_{p-1}x^{p-1} + \cdots + a_0\\
\implies  DP(x) & = f(x+1) - f(x) \\
&= a_p ((x+1)^p - a_p x^p) + a_{p-1}((x+1)^{p-1} - x^p) + \cdots\\
& = a_p (px^{p-1} + O(x^{p-2})) + a_{p-1}((p-1)x^{p-2} + O(x^{p-3})) + \cdots
\end{align}
$$
The finite difference $DP$ will be a polynomial of degree $p-1$ with leading coefficient $p a_p$.
Apply this one more time, we find
$$D^2P(x) = DP(x+1) - DP(x) = P(x+2) - 2P(x+1) + P(x)$$
is a polynomial of degree $p-2$ and leading coefficient $p(p-1) a_p$.
When one repeat this process $p$ times, we will bring the degree of
$D^pP(x)$ down to $0$ and $D^pP(x)$ become a constant with value $p(p-1)(p-2)\cdots(1) a_p = p! a_p$.

$$(D^p P)(x) \stackrel{def}{=} ((\underbrace{D\cdots D}_{p \text{times}}) P)(x)
= \sum_{k=0}^p (-1)^{p-k} \binom{p}{k} P(x+k) = p!a_p$$

If integer $d$ divides $P(n)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$,
then $d$ divides $(DP)(n) = P(n+1) - P(n)$ for every $n$. 
By a similar argument, $d$ divides $(D^2 P)(n) = (DP)(n+1) - (DP)(n)$ for every $n$. Repeat this procedure $p$ times, we find $d$ divides the constant $(D^p P)(n) = p!a_p$.

From these, we can deduce $\gcd\{ P(n) : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ divides $p!a_p$.

This bound is sort of optimal. Consider following family of polynomials:

$$S_p(x) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{p!}x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-p+1), & p > 0\\
1, & p = 0
\end{cases}$$

It is easy to check they satisfy a recurrence relation

$$S_p(x+1) - S_p(x) = S_{p-1}(x),\quad\text{ for } p \ge 0$$

Notice $S_0(n) = 1$ for every integer $n$ and $S_p(0) = 0$ is an integer.
If $S_{p-1}(n)$ is an integer for every $n$, then

$$S_p(n) = S_p(0) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} S_{p-1}(k)$$
is also any integer for every $n$. By principle of induction, we find for any $p \ge 0$, $S_p(x)$ is a polynomial which take integer values at integer $x$.

Multiply $S_p(x)$ by $p!$, we obtain a polynomial $p!S_p(x)$ with integer coefficients, leading coefficient one and $p!$ divides $p!S_p(n)$ for every $n$.
As a result, $p!$ divides $\gcd\{ p!S_p(n) : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

$p!S_p(n)$ will be an example for $P$ where $\gcd\{ P(n) : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ 
equals to $p! a_p$.